# SetDecimalSeparator Doesn't work in real device

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

I have a UITextField with this code bellow, who get the values and transform in money format:

```
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
[numberFormatter setCurrencySymbol:@"$"];
[numberFormatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
[numberFormatter setMinimumFractionDigits:2];
```

This code works well, but when I try to change my decimal separator (comma ',') to (point '.') with this command:

```
  [numberFormatter setDecimalSeparator:@"."];
```

My TextField continues showing the comma as the separator but this time I can not edit my textfield, How I can solve this problem?

```
EDIT
```

In Ipad simulator this code works well, but when I put this code in my real Ipad (Language from Brazil) This code not work!

Answer (score 4):

I spotted the same issue. It seems that NSNumberFormatter with NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle style ignores decimalSeparator settings. I had to change to NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle in order to set own decimalSeparator.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I also faced same issue in all iPad devices but in all iPhone devices it was working fine. So i added following code:

```
[numberFormatter setDecimalSeparator:@","];  
[numberFormatter setGroupingSeparator:@"."];
```

OR vice versa

```
[numberFormatter setDecimalSeparator:@"."];  
[numberFormatter setGroupingSeparator:@","];
```

Now in all devices its working fine.
Thanks